# Disabled option for windows in Azure App Service in .NET 8 code

Tags: .net, azure, azure-appservice, .net-8.0

When trying to provision an App Service resource with Runtime Stack .NET 8, only the "Linux" operating system selection is enabled.

The documentation indicates that it is enabled for "windows" and "linux":
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-app-service-support-for-net-8

[image]

Has anyone been able to solve this?

Selecting the Windows operating system in .NET 8

Comment: Are you using a new - or preexisting - App Service Plan? What pricing tier and generation are you using?

Comment: I have not yet selected the Plan, like in the image I left.

Comment: I tried it just now and I get the same results - I can only create a .NET 8 app-service for a Linux environment. It's probably just because it's still in Beta/Preview though. .NET 8 is very, very new, and Azure App Services generally lag behind, sometimes as much as 6-9 months (IIRC, it took a whole year for AAS to get .NET 4.8 - and we still don't have 4.8.1 ugh).

Answer (score 0):

**I checked from my end, I also could see only Linux is enabled for .Net 8 preview version.**

[image]

As ***@Dai*** mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/what-s-new-for-azure-app-service-at-build-2023/ba-p/3822925), .Net 8 for Azure App Service is currently in preview and issues are expected, and we have to wait for official version as per answers in [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1303909/when-will-net-8-be-available-on-azure-app-services).:

[image]

---

As an alternative, we can deploy the **.Net8 web application** to **Azure App Service** through **visual studio.**

- Right click on the **project** and create **publish profile** by selecting **Azure App Service(Windows)**:

[image]
[image]

Before publishing the profile, click on `Settings=>Show all settings` ,change the **Deployment Mode** to `Self-contained`:

[image]

[image]

**Running deployed application:**

[image]

***Though the application deploys successfully, the Runtime version of the App Service will still be the older version i.e., .NET 6.0**:*

[image]